# Iniciales de nombres y apellidos con PHP

Tags: php, string, funciones

Tengo la siguiente duda y no he podido resolverla, he tratado con **strings**, pero nada me ha resultado. Por eso solicito de su amable ayuda.

Tengo lo siguiente:

De mi `bd` hago una consulta sencilla donde llamo el nombre de la persona `$nombre = $row['name'];`

Ahora digamos que al traer ese dato, me da el siguiente nombre:

```php
echo $nombre //JUAN CARLOS GIRALDO BERNAL.
```

Lo que busco hacer, es pasarle una función o *string* que me permita obtener las iniciales de los nombres y apellidos completos. Es decir, el resultado del nombre que cite debería darme *JCGB*.

Espero me hayan entendido y agradezco que me pueda explicar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) de php para obtener un array de tu string:

```
$nombre = 'JUAN CARLOS GIRALDO BERNAL';
function getIniciales($nombre){
    $name = '';
    $explode = explode(' ',$nombre);
    foreach($explode as $x){
        $name .=  $x[0];
    }
    return $name;    
}

echo getIniciales($nombre);
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahh estaba en lo mismo, olvide que la concatenacion es con .=

Comment: Es justo la función que estaba necesitando, ya la probe y todo OK, estudiaré más sobre explode. gracias